# Modifying the Ubuntu 20.04 Desktop logout delay timer

Tags: 20.04, logout

Does anyone have any suggestions as to how to change the default delay (60 seconds) when logging out of the Ubuntu 20.04 desktop? In other words, the timer seen in this window reached immediately after selecting the top bar Logout option:
[image: Log Out panel]

Comment: Being able to reduce it to some other value under one minute would be handy (eg 20 seconds).

Comment: Since I've now removed reboot and poweroff menu choices, that would be fine, thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is the  [gnome-shell-extension EndSessionTimer](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/3216/end-session-timer/)  I have tried to create.. Not sure if any errors.. I have tested in two systems with Ubuntu 20.04 for 48Hrs..

First, Install the Extension and Enable it.

[image]

The default timeout is set to 10secs.

You can control the timeout between 5 Secs to 60 Secs Via Dconf-Editor or gsettings key.

To Control the timeout other than 10 secs.. which is default.. you must compile the schemas..

***To Compile the Schemas:***

change directory to the installed extension `EndSessionTimer`

```
cd $HOME/.local/share/gnome-shell/extensions/EndSessionTimer@pratap.fastmail.fm
```

and run the command

```
./compile-schemas-script
```

[image]

Now Refresh the gnome-shell via "Alt+F2 r Enter" method.

Now you can control the endSessionTimer value between 5 to 60 secs via Dconf-editor or gsettings

***Dconf-editor:***

[image]

***gsettings:***

```
gsettings set org.gnome.shell.extensions.end-session-timer time-out 14
```

[image]

Comment: Many thanks for your formula. I tried it but, whilst the gsetting is recognised and present in dconf-editor it doesn't appear to have any effect (Ubuntu 20.04) on the logout time delay (still stuck at 60 seconds, no matter what time is set).

Comment: did you turn on the extension??

Comment: https://imgur.com/yNVsrb6

Comment: Excellent. Thank you - that's what I was missing. Now works.

Comment: Sorry, was in a rush. Most satisfied! Thanks.

Comment: Isn't there a way to do that by modifying some system property instead of downloading something? I can't download stuff on my computer...

Comment: Is there instructions to install this on a headless system? I need to change a system image that's deployed via iPXE and I don't have a GUI to install it. Also it need to be intalled systemwide. Thanks!

Comment: @ViníciusFerrão Hi, that can be installed via terminal but it wont work in recent versions as I could not make it to work. can you provide your gnome-shell version please

Comment: It's on Gnome Shell 42 (22.04.3 LTS) so we hit a dead end.

Comment: @ViníciusFerrão yup 22.04 is a bit difficult for me to adopt changes from 20.04 as I am in gnome-shell v45 and adopting my extensions from v44 to v45.